# Set up IIS to ask authentication for only some webpages of the website

Tags: iis-6, authentication

I have a website (in IIS6) that has to be accessible from both intranet as the internet.
Situation now: for every page you get prompted for username and password (via integrated windows authentication)
But the webpages 'info' and 'contact' should be accessible anonymously, without authentication this. All the other pages of the website should prompt you for UN/PW,
preferably via integrated windows authentication.

How do I managed this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Within IIS right click the site and go to properties.  Under Directory Security set it to windows auth and uncheck anonymous.  Then (still within IIS) click the + next to the site and go to the folder(s) containing the pages for contact and info.  Right click those folders or files and go to properties and set them back to anonymous and uncheck the windows auth on those.  That should do it.

Comment: Thx! Unfortunately it still asks authentication but I guess it has to do with the fact that there are lots of other files needed other than default.aspx that will have to configured like this. Lot of work to do